# GD Library extension not available with this PHP installation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I set up a laravel app on my virtual private server and it all works fine. On trying to upload an image i get the following error.

```
GD Library extension not available with this PHP installation.
```

I have installed php_gd on the server and it is enabled and still the same. What do i need to do to make it work?

Comment: And do you see it enabled, when you check `phpinfo()`?

Comment: Yes @tereško it is enabled. I do not understand anymore.

Comment: Try with restart your server and also tried with virtual machine.